# How to remove 180+ days old files from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, cloud-storage

I'm using Firebase for my Android app. Which has more than 600GB data stored by my users. Which is affecting my billing. That's why I want to remove old files from my cloud storage.

After doing some research, I added a life cycle rule in my Cloud Storage like below...

[image: Life Cycle Rule]

It shows rule will be active in 24 days. But my question is will it remove all the old files automatically. Or this rule is only applicable for files uploaded after I created this rule.

If the second option is true, then are there any ways delete them all ;_;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#introduction) suggests that your lifecycle configuration should work for all files:

> You can assign a lifecycle management configuration to a bucket. The
>   configuration contains a set of rules which apply to **current** and
>   **future** objects in the bucket. When an object meets the criteria of one
>   of the rules, Cloud Storage automatically performs a specified action
>   on the object.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#behavior) also says it might take some time to activate:

> Updates to your lifecycle configuration may take up to 24 hours to go
>   into effect. This means that when you change your lifecycle
>   configuration, Object Lifecycle Management may still perform actions
>   based on the old configuration for up to 24 hours.